# Do I need water protection over tile grout in my bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, tile, sealing, grout, ceramic-tile

A handyman suggested to me that I might need to periodically apply water-sealant to the tile and grout on the tile wall of my bathtub. Is he correct?

If so, what's a good sealant to use,  how is it best applied, and how often should I re-apply it? (It's probably been 15 years since the previous owner refinished this bathroom and put in a tile wall, so probably been 15 years since any sealing was done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a good cleaning, (Tris-odium Phosphate and a stiff brush), Apply generic furniture lemon oil. Wipe off excess. I have been setting tile for years and this works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question is yes. It never hurts to have sealer on your grout. Especially in wet areas. I've never used lemon oil though. A good water based sealer generally does the trick. Check the particular sealer you buy to see how often you need to re-apply it. It varies from manufacturer and quality of sealer used.